# UIImagePickerController returned image woes

Tags: iphone, properties, uiimageview, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePickerController that lets the user pick an image from their library, edit it, and then save the product out to disk. Before it saves, however, I need to update a UIImageView to hold the edited photo. But when I go to set the UIImageView's image property, the program crashes. It still can save to disk.

The UIImageView is an IBOutlet and the dimensions are 88x88, if anybody cares.

I can reproduce this issue on a device (iPhone 3GS running iOS4) and in the simulator (iOS 4).

Answer (score 0):

Don't you know what the error is? Especially in iOS4 you should see an entire stack trace in your log.

Most likely culprit would be a bad Interface Builder link... from there you should do retain count on your actual UIImage to see where it is when you assign it to the ImageView...

Anything after that, I suspect, would be application specific.

Comment: i have tried removing it from IB and creating it programatically and that didnt work. I also checked the retain count and it was 1. The app proceeded to crash. What should I do now?

Comment: also, that very same image can be converted to NSData and saved to disk. That works.

Comment: Where does the UIImageView come from? To rule out your image as the problem, replace the UIImageView.image assignment by something failsafe like [UIImage imageNamed:@"..."]

Comment: which reminds me: doing image stuff on an iphone results in a lot of didReceiveMemoryWarnings, which, when not properly handled, might unload your UIImageView, resulting in EXC_BAD_ACCESS. put in a -(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{NSLog(@"Ha! NOT unloading");} and see what happens.